# Excel Cell value based on VLookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have my sheet like below 
 [image]

I need to automatically fille the ones in Red based on the look up value created in another sheet of same workbook. the lookup list is as below: 
 
[image]

if it is under partner  - it should show as partner, and if there is no value in lookup list , it can return "unknown" as default.

Any idea on how to get this done?

Comment: @pnuts Unfortunately no. While the solution worked for most of the cells,  It was working for all the cells, even though there were matching. Also, in terms of UI it was getting very difficult to differentiate what they were by color hence i opted to create a new column rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a formula in your Company Type column.

Assuming the sheet containing the lookup data is called "data", and partners are listed in column A and competitors in column B. If you're trying to get the company type for the company in cell A2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Data'!$A:$A,A2)>0,"Partner",IF(COUNTIF('Data'!$B:$B,A2)>0,"Competitor","Unknown"))
```

Briefly:

```
COUNTIF('Data'!$A:$A,A2)>0
```

Counts all occurences that match the company name in A2 in the list of partner companys in column A of the Data sheet. If there is more than 0, this code block will return TRUE. This is then used to guide if statements determining the  company type.

Using [this example company data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfCdO.png), I produced the [lookup results shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R38Zm.png). Hopefully this is what you're after.

Regards,

Xeozim

Edit: switched to COUNTIF for a simpler check

Comment: Thanx @Xeozim.. Just tried..  worked like a charm.. Thank you